# +grails debug forked +suspend

Tags: debugging, grails, intellij-idea

Grails app suspends at startup in --debug-forked mode.
I am runing app with --debug-fork parameter but it suspends and waits until debugger conncects to it, then debugger disconnects, and app waits for debugger again. When debugger connects second time - app continues bootstraping. 
How can I pass syspend=y parameter to ForkedGrailsProcessConfig to avoid such annoying behaviour?

I am using grails 2.4.4 in IntelliJ Idea 14 .

Answer (score 1):

I havent tried it myself but from

http://naleid.com/blog/2014/11/10/debugging-grails-forked-mode

you should be able to get it running with

```
// jvmArgs make it so that we can run in forked mode without having to use the `--debug-fork` flag
// and also has suspend=n so that it will start up without forcing you to  connect a remote debugger first
def jvmArgs = ['-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005']

grails.project.fork = [
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true, jvmArgs: jvmArgs],
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false, jvmArgs: jvmArgs],
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false, jvmArgs: jvmArgs],
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, jvmArgs: jvmArgs]
]
```